# HTML link text everywhere? (Different domains)

Tags: html, css

Very conceptual question here - not sure if it even can be done.

I have a website with different domains, but I made it so that the look and feel of both websites are the same. I know I can have HTML call images so that if I ever need to change the image, I just change the image (same location) and keep the original name.

But my problem is in both domains, there are the same footers. If I update the footer, I have to update it everywhere. Is it ever possible to "link up" text so that I only need to change the text on one primary location, and it changes everywhere the text is called?

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on server-side code? Haven't heard of that before.

Comment: Server side codes, scripts, markup languages etc. like PHP, ASP run by server unlike client side ones, like HTML, JS... I think we can roughly say that you have more control and dynamism with the server side codes. My humble opinion is it's not a one paragraph long issue obviously.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: [server-side includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Put your common elements (e.g. footers, headers, menus, etc.) into separate files and include them in the page dynamically. Here is the template I use for pages on one of the websites I run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title here</title>
<!--#include file="filehead.txt" -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!--#include file="header.html" -->
<article>
<h1>Page title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</article>
<!--#include file="menu.html" -->
<!--#include file="footer.shtml" -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Files are included using the simple syntax `<!--#include file="filename" -->`.

You can also do useful things like include the date that the page was last updated, various pieces of information about the server, and all sorts of other exciting things!

More information on SSIs:

- [Apache SSI tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html)
- [Site management: SSIs](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/includes.html)
- [Javascriptkit's guide to SSIs](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/ssi.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to make it make some server-side magic. But since you ask for pure HTML solution:

Yes, you can do it using `<iframe>` ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)).

Comment: If your websites are popular I wouldn't use it because of performance concerns (additional requests). Rather, I would go with server-side magic.